# What language is this OED entry in?

Tags: dialects, historical-change, middle-english

I came across this citation in the OED entry<sup>1</sup> for fag (4th meaning, "a knot in cloth"):

> 1464 Act. 4 Edw. IV, c. i, ― En cas que ascune autiel diversite ou Rawe, Skawe, cokell ou fagge, aveigne destre en ascun part des ditz draps.

I *think* that refers to an act of law as opposed to a play but, either way, what language is that? Presumably some variant of English but which? It seems far closer to French than modern English.
What I understand of it, I glean from French and Spanish. My English doesn't help at all.

So, what is this English (?) called? Based on the year, I assume it must come under the general heading of Middle English, but I can make far less sense of it that I can of, for example, the [Canterbury Tales](http://canterburytales.org/canterbury_tales.html). Is this a different language? Not Middle English at all?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Available [here](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67608?rskey=hfLEm3&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid), if you have access.</sub>

Comment: Thus,  since this about a sentence in French, I'm not sure it's on topic.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Let's not be legalistic. This is about English. To consider this off-topic is to ignore thought.

Comment: @AlanCarmack the question is basically asking i) what dialect of English is this weird language (to which the answer, apparently, is that it isn't English at all) and ii) what is it doing in the OED. Both are on topic, including the first since, at the time of asking, I was assuming that it was a form of English.

Comment: This is section V (2) of the Cloths, Trade, etc. Act 1464.  In the English version the full subsection read "(2) and in case any such difference or raw or skaw cokel or fagge happen to be in any part of the said cloths, streits, or kerseys, that then a seal of lead, and by the treasurer of England for the time being provided, shall be set and hanged in the lowest part of the said cloth, streit, or kersey, for perfect knowledge to be had to the buyer thereof" which in effect says that faults in cloth being sold should be marked with lead to draw attention to them.

Comment: Thank you @Henry for providing the translation. I was wondering if this  was also the first use of ditz as in ditzy.

Comment: Given the era, it's likely to be Norman French.

Comment: [*ditz* is Norman French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dit#Old_French) for *said* (legalese for *mentioned earlier*) as a plural agreeing with *draps*.  In modern French it would be [*dits*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dits#French)

Comment: @Henry Whence also the English *drapes*, for long heavy curtains. Terdon, you might be so kind as to translate Old/Middle/Norman French bits into English for the vast majority of our readers who have no French at all.

Comment: @tchrist you give me too much credit. The best I can do is "In case any variety of  Rawe, Skawe, cokell or fagge, is present(?) in any part of the said cloths". I'd guess *Rawe, Skawe* and *cokell* are other types of damage a cloth may have (tear, scuff, threadbare, perhaps) but that's as far as my "understanding" goes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's [Law French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_French), the normal language of law in England until well after 1464.

The words Rawe, Skawe, cokell [and] fagge are evidently English words, not French ones, presumably either because there weren't corresponding French terms (at least in Law French), or because it was important to cover every case in this statute.

So, while the rest of the text is in Legal French, it still serves as a valid example of the usage of the *English* word *fag* since this is an English use of an English word in an English law for English people. That the rest of the law happens to be writtren in French doesn't change this.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also explain what this is doing in the OED? Is Law French considered English somehow? I get that it was used in England at the time but, linguistically speaking, can it be considered English and, if not, what is it doing in the OED?

Comment: I assume it is because this is the earliest known example of the **English** word 'fag' in this sense. The fact that it is in a non-English sentence doesn't change this.

Comment: Oh. I haven't come across something like this before. I don't see a French citation in the definition of the word *attaché*, for example. Could it be because the citation is in a language that was, at the time, the official language of the British Isles? It does look as though there's something specific to Law French that makes it a valid source for the OED.

Comment: This is not a French use! This is an English use of an English word in an English law for English people. The language of the law at the time was Law French, but it used that English word.

Comment: Ah! OK, now I get what you mean. I edited your post to make it clearer (to me). If you decide to roll it back, please add a similar clarification in your own words.

Comment: In other wordsv@terdon, if I understand Colin's answer,   it's like this *Ghjhtgg  rhbgfth ghgujb Rawe, Skawe, cokell fagge hihyhjhg byhgyhh huujhvty jhgtyjhh*. The sentence is basically in gobblygook but contains some English words, rather than being entirely in gobblygook.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I think the most important point is that this was a language used to set English laws in England at a time when the line between English and French was a good deal more blurry than it is today.

Comment: Not really. The conquerors spoke French. The 'native English' didn't. There was a clear distinction between the two languages. This was still true 398 years after the landing at Hastings.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I'm sure that's true, but the language known as "English" today is heavily influenced by both the "native" and "conqueror" tongues. So it still seems reasonable to call it English, of a sort. No less than the 'native' language, anyway.

Comment: Before you dismiss Norman French entirely, it is still used in Parliament to show the monarch's assent ([_La Reine le veult_](http://www.parliament.uk/about/mps-and-lords/principal/interviews/clerkparliaments2/)) and when sending bills to 'the other place'. Viz. page nine of [this document on parliamentary tradition](https://www.parliament.uk/documents/commons-information-office/g07.pdf)

Comment: Your first sentence is unclear and/or not very specific. What do you mean by "Law"? The promulgation of Law or its practice, or something else? Even your Wikipedia link says that the ***1362** ("Statute of Pleading") acknowledged this change by ordaining that thenceforward court proceedings be conducted in English*. Thus, in at least one aspect, Law French was hardly "the normal language of law in England until well after 1464."

Comment: Verbal court proceedings and written Laws aren't the same, @AlanCarmack

Comment: @Beanluc "Law French" was the verbal language of the courts, until 1362; after that, English, Latin was the written language of the courts. I'm wondering what the link to Law  French has to do with a citation from the Acts of Parliament  written in French.